# summarizing adjacent subnets with python netaddr cidr_merge

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of IPNetworks that will not merge with [`netaddr.cidr_merge`](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#netaddr.cidr_merge) even though some are adjacent.  Am I doing something wrong?

```python-repl
>>> from netaddr import IPNetwork, cidr_merge
>>> iplist = [
         IPNetwork('10.105.205.8/29'), 
         IPNetwork('10.105.205.16/28'), 
         IPNetwork('10.105.205.32/27'), 
         IPNetwork('10.105.205.64/26'), 
         IPNetwork('10.105.205.128/26'),
         IPNetwork('10.105.205.192/28'),
         IPNetwork('10.105.205.208/29'),
         IPNetwork('10.105.206.48/28'),
         IPNetwork('10.105.206.80/28')
    ]
>>> summary = cidr_merge(iplist)
>>> summary == iplist
    True
```

I'm using Python 3.3.4 and netaddr 7.12 on Mac OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: after some playing around with this.  I've found that if I add IPNetwork('10.105.204.0/29') to iplist then it will summarize further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@duskwuff -

Thank you for your reply. I agree with the first part but the second...I think I know where your going with it, but it's not 100% accurate. For instance if I take an edited list from above, and append 10.105.205.0/29.  The subnets will summarize to a /25.  Yes they must be a power of 2, but all parts of the whole subnet must be present before netaddr will summarize, regardless if they are of equal size.

```
   iplist =[
        IPNetwork('10.105.205.8/29'), 
        IPNetwork('10.105.205.16/28'), 
        IPNetwork('10.105.205.32/27'), 
        IPNetwork('10.105.205.64/26'),
        ]
    >>> iplist.append(IPNetwork('10.105.205.0/29'))
    >>> netaddr.cidr_merge(iplist)
        [IPNetwork('10.105.205.0/25')]
```

Answer (score 4):

`netaddr` is working correctly here. Not all adjacent subnets can be summarized.

For instance, consider the subnets `10.255.255.0/24` and `11.0.0.0/24`. While they are adjacent — the first one ends with `10.255.255.255`, and the second begins with `11.0.0.0` — they cannot be summarized, as they cross a boundary that is much larger than either of these two networks.

Additionally, regardless of how they are aligned, two adjacent networks can only be joined together if they're of equal size. Mismatched sizes cannot be combined into a single range, because the size of the combined network will not be a power of 2.