# Can any one help me in writing a script for the following scenario

Tags: unix

I have the following scenario.
I have a file with the following content.

```
start-I/p          end-I/p          code
10.35.210.1       10.35.210.255     User1
10.35.145.1       10.35.145.255     User2
```

I want the output in the following manner.

```
ip             code
10.35.210.1    user1
10.35.210.2    user1
10.35.210.3    user1
10.35.210.4    user1
```

and so on until

```
10.35.210.255  user1
10.35.145.1    user2
10.35.145.2    user2
10.35.145.3    user2
10.35.145.4    user2
so on till
10.35.145.255  user2.
```

Can any one help me with a suitable solution?

Comment: Too broad - you need to make an attempt at this first and then come back if you have any specific problems.

Comment: hi , I am trying in shell scripting to achieve this...But not able to do so...

Comment: You should post the shell script that you've written so far, even though it's not working, and then people here can help you to fix the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use python its a matter of only two loops.convert IP to integer [[Conversion from IP string to integer, and backward in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619685/conversion-from-ip-string-to-integer-and-backward-in-python]), increment it and print it along with the user
 Thats it

Comment: The client wants us to finish it using either shell scripting or pl/sql only.