# Python - ip <-> subnet match?

Tags: python, ip, subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if an ip is in a network in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819355/how-can-i-check-if-an-ip-is-in-a-network-in-python)

What is the easy way to match subnet to an ip address in python, so that if the ip address is in the subnet I can choose it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. What are you choosing, the IP or the subnet? Is the question "how can I tell if an IP address is in a particular subnet?" Or what?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Python 3.3+, you can use [ipaddress](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ipaddress.html) module:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('192.0.43.10') in ipaddress.ip_network('192.0.0.0/16')
True
```

If your Python installation is older than 3.3, you can use [this backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress).

---

If you want to evaluate a *lot* of IP addresses this way, you'll probably want to calculate the netmask upfront, like

```
n = ipaddress.ip_network('192.0.0.0/16')
netw = int(n.network_address)
mask = int(n.netmask)
```

Then, for each address, calculate the binary representation with one of

```
a = int(ipaddress.ip_address('192.0.43.10'))
a = struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, '192.0.43.10'))[0]
a = struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton('192.0.43.10'))[0]  # IPv4 only
```

Finally, you can simply check:

```
in_network = (a & mask) == netw
```

Comment: anyway to do this more efficiently for a giant set of tables? ex. I have a table of some 100,000 of these :)

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf Updated the answer for that case as well.

Comment: The second approach, which calculates the netmask upfront, does not seem to work. I followed the exact step, and in the end, `in_network` is `False`. I am using the port of the module to 2.6 and 2.7. Using `ipaddr` (https://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/) is the same: yielding a False for the above example. Note that I imported the `py` module files directly without run the `setup.py`, which I don't think is an issue.

Comment: @Causality Great catch! Fixed by switching to ints.

Comment: Has since been [imported to older python versions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress).

Comment: @BelminFernandez Thanks, I've added the backport (by yours truly ;) ) to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If for a given IP you want to find a prefix from a long list of prefixes, then you can implement [longest prefix match](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_prefix_match). You first build a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from your list of prefixes, and later, you traverse the tree looking for the furthest leaf that matches your prefix.

It sounds scary, but it is not that bad :)