# how to perform AND operation on ip address and subnet mask in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if an ip is in a network in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819355/how-can-i-check-if-an-ip-is-in-a-network-in-python)

I have one destination ip address from a file suppose `ip1 = 172.16.0.34`; and I have one more file having (subnet, mask, next-hop) i.e `172.16.0.0`, `255.255.255.0`, `117.120.10.1`

I have to check whether the incoming address ip1 matches the subnet entry for a particular route,after being ANDed with the netmask of that entry in the routing table. If the destination matches under mask,add the route to the list of feasible routes for this packet

Comment: Something tells me this is homework, and your post was copy-pasted from the pdf handout

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming their strings to begin with:

```
ipadd = '192.168.1.1'
mask = '255.255.0.0'
anded = list()
for ip, m in zip(ipadd.split('.'),mask.split('.')):
   anded.append(str(int(ip) & int(m)))
subnet = '.'.join(anded)
```

Comment: I tried this but it's throwing an error:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them in a Array then compare ! it's just my suggestion ...