# Check if two CIDR addresses intersect?

Tags: python, ip-address, cidr

Given two CIDR addresses say 192.168.2.0/14 and 192.168.2.0/32

How do I check if two ip addresses overlap in "python2.6"??

I have gone through netaddr and it allows to check if
192.168.2.0 is in CIDR address 192.168.2.0/14 by

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPAddress
bool = IPAddress("192.168.2.0") in IPNetwork("192.168.2.0/14"):
```

But how to check for two CIDR address??

I found a reference :: [How can I check if an ip is in a network in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819355/how-can-i-check-if-an-ip-is-in-a-network-in-python)

Comment: FYI, 192.168.2.0/32 is a single IP address (192.168.2.0), not a subnet.

Comment: Would you accept an answer that is not python specific?

Comment: Thnx for the info. I need it in python but your explanation might be useful.

Comment: My explanation would have been the same as rob's.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using [ipaddr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddr):

```
>>> import ipaddr
>>> n1 = ipaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.1.0/24')
>>> n2 = ipaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.2.0/24')
>>> n3 = ipaddr.IPNetwork('192.168.2.0/25')
>>> n1.overlaps(n2)
False
>>> n1.overlaps(n3)
False
>>> n2.overlaps(n3)
True
>>> n2.overlaps(n1)
False
```

Comment: Thanks the library does exactly what I want.

Comment: Does the same code work for IPv6 as well or it supports IPv4 only?

Comment: Work for IPv6. `ipaddr.IPNetwork('::192.168.0.0/120').overlaps(ipaddr.IPNetwork('::192.168.0.0/121'))` returns True  and `ipaddr.IPNetwork('::192.168.4.0/120').overlaps(ipaddr.IPNetwork('::192.168.0.0/121'))` returns False

Comment: Is there any solution in Powershell?

Comment: Is there an online tool for this?

Comment: It's now included in the standard library (`ipaddress`), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77105792

Answer (score 7):

I'll assume you actually want both CIDRs to represent ranges, even though in your example, 192.168.2.0/32 represents only one address.  Also note that in 192.168.2.0/14, the .2. is meaningless, because the 14-bit prefix doesn't reach the third octet.

Anyway, there are a several ways to do this.  You could notice that for them to overlap, one must always be a subset of the other:

```
def cidrsOverlap(cidr0, cidr1):
    return cidr0 in cidr1 or cidr1 in cidr0
```

Or you could notice that for the ranges to overlap, the first range's lowest address must be less than or equal to the second range's highest address, and vice versa.  Thus:

```
def cidrsOverlap(cidr0, cidr1):
    return cidr0.first <= cidr1.last and cidr1.first <= cidr0.last

print cidrsOverlap(IPNetwork('192.168.2.0/24'), IPNetwork('192.168.3.0/24'))
# prints False

print cidrsOverlap(IPNetwork('192.168.2.0/23'), IPNetwork('192.168.3.0/24'))
# prints True
```

Comment: Thanks the range comparison works. 
One more thing, could you find out the ip addresses that are overlapped??

Comment: The ip addresses that are overlapped is the subnet with the smaller range: that is, the higher number after the `/`. Therefore, between 192.168.2.0/23 and 192.168.2.0/24 the addresses that are overlapped are 192.168.2.0/24. Remember, CIDR subnet cannot "overlap". They can only contain a smaller CIDR subnet or not.

Comment: @AJRedDevil Since one is always a subset of the other, the overlap is just the smaller range.  The first address in the overlap (smaller range) is `max(cidr0.first, cidr1.first)`.  The last address is `min(cidr0.last, cidr1.last)`.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote [this](https://github.com/fgiuba/ipconflict) simple command line tool, based on the `netaddr` lib.

```
pip install ipconflict
```

Example:

```
ipconflict 10.0.0.0/22 10.0.1.0/24
```

Output:

```
conflict found: 10.0.1.0/24 <-> 10.0.1.0/22
```

Answer (score 1):

If don't have `netaddr` at hand for testing, but I think you could check if the [first](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/blob/rel-0.7.x/netaddr/ip/__init__.py#L1012) and [last](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/blob/rel-0.7.x/netaddr/ip/__init__.py#L1020) address of the first network are both contained in the second:

```
net_1 = IPNetwork("192.168.2.0/14")
net_2 = IPNetwork("192.168.2.0/32")
if net_1.first in net_2 and net_1.last in net_2:
    # do something
```

BTW, `IPNetwork` [line 1102](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/blob/rel-0.7.x/netaddr/ip/__init__.py#L1102) defines a `__contains__` method. But I'm not certain the [line 1127](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/blob/rel-0.7.x/netaddr/ip/__init__.py#L1127) isn't broken ? You should test and report a bug if it is.

Answer (score 1):

[`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) was added in the in Python 3.3 standard library and is intended to replace what is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17206952).

```py
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

n1 = IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24')
n2 = IPv4Network('192.168.2.0/24')
n3 = IPv4Network('192.168.2.0/25')

n1.overlaps(n2)
# False
n1.overlaps(n3)
# False
n2.overlaps(n3)
# True
n2.overlaps(n1)
# False
```