# Efficiently detect overlapping networks

Tags: python

I know how to detect overlapping networks. There are two ways to do this: by using netaddr's "IPNetwork in IPNetwork" or ipaddress's "overlaps" method. The question is how to find overlapping networks in array in most efficient way.

At the moment, I use this code:

```
networks = {
    IPNetwork('10.1.0.0/24'): 'net2',
    IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/8'): 'net1',
    IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/16'): 'net3',
    IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/24'): 'net4',
    IPNetwork('192.168.0.0/16'): 'net5',
    IPNetwork('192.168.0.0/23'): 'net6',
    IPNetwork('192.168.1.0/24'): 'net7',
    IPNetwork('172.16.0.0/12'): 'net8'
}

net = sorted([key for key in networks.keys()])
for pi in range(0, len(net)-1):
    for si in range(pi+1, len(net)):
        if net[si] in net[pi]:
            print(f'{net[si]} ({networks[net[si]]}) overlaps with '
                  f'{net[pi]} ({networks[net[pi]]})')
```

It does the job, but uses many iterations (e.g. for 8 entries there are 7+6+5+... = 28 comparisons) and I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Maybe you could create a dict like `{"10.1.0": ["10.1.0.0/24"], "10.0.0": ["10.0.0.0/8", "10.0.0.0/16", ...], ...}` to reduce the number of ranges to compare?

Comment: BTW, what library are you using?

Comment: Looks like [this one](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if two CIDR addresses intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206679/check-if-two-cidr-addresses-intersect)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Not a duplicate IMHO. That other question is about checking how two addresses overlap, but OP seems to know that. He's looking for an efficient way (better than O(n²)) to do that for a lot of addresses.

Comment: @tobias_k, I use Python's netaddr library. And yes, I know how to detect overlapping, I'm seeking for effective way to do this with lot of networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle all of your cases, but it may not find EVERY duplicate, e.g. given `(a, a', a'', a''', b)` it will not show that `(a''' overlaps a')`. If you're really interested in the primary supersets, then this code can be simplified

```
from netaddr.ip import IPNetwork
from collections import namedtuple

Network = namedtuple("Network", "name ip")

networks = {
    IPNetwork('10.1.0.0/24'): 'net2',
    IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/8'): 'net1',
    IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/16'): 'net3',
    IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/24'): 'net4',
    IPNetwork('192.168.0.0/16'): 'net5',
    IPNetwork('192.168.0.0/23'): 'net6',
    IPNetwork('192.168.1.0/24'): 'net7',
    IPNetwork('172.16.0.0/12'): 'net8'
}

print("original")
net = sorted([key for key in networks.keys()])
for pi in range(0, len(net)-1):
    for si in range(pi+1, len(net)):
        if net[si] in net[pi]:
            print(f'{net[si]} ({networks[net[si]]}) overlaps with '
                  f'{net[pi]} ({networks[net[pi]]})')

nets = sorted([Network(v, k) for k, v in networks.items()], key=lambda a: a.ip)

print()
print("faster")
aa = None
first = True
for a, b in zip(nets[0:-1], nets[1:]):
  if aa is None:
    aa = a
  if b.ip in aa.ip:
    print(f'{b.ip} ({b.name}) overlaps with {aa.ip} ({aa.name})')
    if not first and aa != a and b.ip in a.ip: 
      # it's already a subset of an earlier one...
      # only if you care about secondary overlaps
      print(f'{b.ip} ({b.name}) overlaps with {a.ip} ({a.name})')
    # aa = a
  elif b.ip in a.ip:
    print(f'{b.ip} ({b.name}) overlaps with {a.ip} ({a.name})')
    aa = a
  else:
    # print(f'! {b.ip} ({b.name}) overlaps with {aa.ip} ({aa.name})')
    aa = None
  first = False
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code also misses some overlaps. You compare current (b.ip) to first (aa.ip) and previous (a.ip) entries and, thus, will miss entries between them. Try with this set of networks: '10.0.0.0/8', '10.0.0.0/23', '10.0.0.0/24', '10.0.0.0/25' and '10.0.1.0/25' - in this case overlaps of two last networks with second one will be missed. But anyway thanks for try.

Comment: Actually, your code is about 4 times faster than my in OP. I think I will reconsider requirements - it doesn't make sense to find all overlaps of one network if there is at least one.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to solve this problem in [firewalld](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/pull/907).

You can achieve `O(n)` detection by presorting the networks ahead of time. Python sorts networks first by network bits (ip address) and then by netmask. This plus address normalization done by `IPv4Network` means that overlapping entries will be adjacent in the sorted list.

The detection is then done by comparing adjacent items:

```python
from ipaddress import IPv4Network

networks = {
    IPv4Network('10.1.0.0/24'): 'net2',
    IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/8'): 'net1',
    IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/16'): 'net3',
    IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/24'): 'net4',
    IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/16'): 'net5',
    IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/23'): 'net6',
    IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24'): 'net7',
    IPv4Network('172.16.0.0/12'): 'net8'
}

networks_list = sorted(networks.keys())

prev_network = networks_list.pop(0)
for current_network in networks_list:
    if prev_network.overlaps(current_network):
        print("Network {} overlaps {}".format(prev_network, current_network))
    prev_network = current_network
```

Results:

```
Network 10.0.0.0/8 overlaps 10.0.0.0/16
Network 10.0.0.0/16 overlaps 10.0.0.0/24
Network 192.168.0.0/16 overlaps 192.168.0.0/23
Network 192.168.0.0/23 overlaps 192.168.1.0/24
```