# Matching IP addresses to a list of subnets and then returning the firewall

Tags: python, bash

I'm looking for some pointers to send me in the right direction. I have a list of about 60 variable subnets which reside on various firewalls around the globe.

```
10.10.10.0/24  Firewall-Denver
10.10.20.0/25  Firewall-NewYork
10.10.30.0/28  Firewall-China
```

etc ...

I have another (very long) list of IP addresses which I would like to check against the list of subnets (I assume a python module would be best placed to do this?) and then I want to return the firewall which that subnet is associated with.

```
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.174
10.10.20.3
10.10.30.19
```

So return something like

```
10.10.10.1   Firewall-Denver
10.10.10.174 Firewall-Denver
10.10.20.3   Firewall-NewYork
10.10.30.19  Firewall-China
```

Thank you for your advice in advance. So I am not just looking for the IP/Subnet but a different key to be returned.

Comment: No they are a range of different masks. I've updated to reflect

Comment: Are you using python 3 or python 2?

Comment: I can use whatever version as this is a mining project which I am doing

Comment: How are you inputting the subnet and firewall list? Is it a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it will be a predefined list.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819355/how-can-i-check-if-an-ip-is-in-a-network-in-python, other than that just read file line by line and compare to dictionary with keys being your firewall addresses and values - their names.

Comment: I did have a look at that but I think Farhan.K answer below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `ipaddress` module in python 3:

```
import ipaddress

ipsub = {"10.10.10.0/24": "Firewall-Denver", "10.10.20.0/25": "Firewall-NewYork"}
iplist = ["10.10.10.1","10.10.10.174","10.10.20.126"]

ipfirewall = {}

for i in ipsub:
    for j in iplist:
        if ipaddress.ip_address(j) in ipaddress.ip_network(i):
            ipfirewall[j] = ipsub[i]
```

Output:

```
>>> ipfirewall
{'10.10.10.1': 'Firewall-Denver', '10.10.20.126': 'Firewall-NewYork', '10.10.10.174': 'Firewall-Denver'}
```

If you want to output a nested list then write it to a file, use this instead:

```
import ipaddress

ipsub = {"10.10.10.0/24": "Firewall-Denver" ,"10.10.20.0/25": "Firewall-NewYork"}
iplist = ["10.10.10.1","10.10.10.174","10.10.20.126"]

ipfirewall = []


for i in ipsub:
    for j in iplist:
        if ipaddress.ip_address(j) in ipaddress.ip_network(i):
            ipfirewall.append([j,ipsub[i]])
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in ipfirewall)
```

Output:

```
>>> ipfirewall
[['10.10.10.1', 'Firewall-Denver'], ['10.10.10.174', 'Firewall-Denver'], ['10.10.20.126', 'Firewall-NewYork']]
```

Comment: Hi Farhan, if I run the command from a file with 'python3 commands.py' I get no output. I have everything in there and there is no error. Do I need to do something else if it is in a file?

Comment: How have you entered the list of ip subnets and firewalls into the script? You could write the output to a file using `with open('filename', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in ipfirewall)`

Comment: It's working from the python shell but I am just getting garble in the file from the commany line running the file when using :


    with open('filename', 'w') as file: file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in ipfirewall)

Comment: I changed the \t to no character and I am getting the IP address now but not the firewall. Almost there!

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you what I meant. Is that what you are doing?
I'm not sure why you are getting just the IP address but not the firewall. Could you update your post to show your full code?

Comment: I used the second example and it worked! Thank you! Could I ask what these lines do?

1.  ipfirewall.append([j,ipsub[i]]) ---and this line ---
2. file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in ipfirewall)

Comment: `ipfirewall.append([j,ipsub[i]])` adds `j` (the ip address) and `ipsub[i]` (the firewall) to the list `ipfirewall` to create a nested list. `file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in ipfirewall)` puts a `\t` (tab) between the ip address and firewall then writes it to the file along with a `\n` (new line).  It does this for every entry in `ipfirewall`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again for your help.I have a much better understanding . iplist will actually be passed in from a bash script but I'll open up a new Question for this.