# Python IP range to IP range match

Tags: python, ip-address

Is there any method to check if some IP addresses from a network range are present in the subnets of another IP range?

```
Example: 10.0.1.0/18 in 123.1.0.0/8
```

If it exists, I need it to return True, else False.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Python 3.3, you can use the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module of the standard library:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address, IPv4Network

IPv4Address('192.0.2.6') in IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28')
# True
IPv4Address('10.0.1.0') in IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28')
# False
```

If you mean if the networks overlap, use `overlaps`:

```
In [14]: IPv4Network('10.0.1.0/24').overlaps(IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28'))
Out[14]: False
```

Note that this module was marked as provisional in Python 3.3, but no longer is in 3.6. So enjoy it!

Comment: This is for only "/32" Ip not range. Read the question properly

Comment: Thanks for the Overlaps Suggestion thats what I was looking for exactly

Answer (score 4):

```
from ipaddress import ip_address, ip_network
```

NOTE: Other answers specifically point at IPv4Address, IPv4Network, but ip_address and ip_network simply call the IPv4 OR IPv6 version when needed.

```
addr = ip_address('10.0.1.0')
```

NOTE: the sample network you provided is not a true `/8` network, so the ip_network will respond with an error of `ValueError: 123.1.0.0/8 has host bits set`

To get past this, by forcing the ipaddress library to essentially round down to the nearest network address, you can set `strict=False` and Python will find the nearest, lower address for a `/8` network: `123.0.0.0`

```
netw = ip_network('123.1.0.0/8', strict=False)

print(addr in netw)
```

Then it is simply a matter of testing using the `in` keyword.

If you want to test every address in a network range against every address in another network range, then:

```
net1 = ip_network('10.0.1.0/18', strict=False)
net2 = ip_network('123.1.0.0/8', strict=False)

for addr in net1:
    if addr in net2:
        print(addr, 'True')
    else:
        print(addr, 'False')
```

In addition, networks can be converted into sets:

```
n1 = set(net1)
n2 = set(net2)
```

And Python sets have the ability show any overlap OR inclusion (subset/superset relationships).

```
n1.isdisjoint(n2)
n1.issubset(n2)
n2.issubset(n1)
n2.issuperset(n1)
```

etc.

Comment: I need a range to range match not for a third IP, Please read the question correctly

Comment: Sir: three of us are trying to answer your question and your reply to most of us has been: read the question properly. I might suggest that the question could be phrased more carefully: potentially with a more concrete example of what you mean by "check if one Ip from a network range is present in the subnets of Other Ip range". That might help all of us provide an answer that meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the accepted answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819355/how-can-i-check-if-an-ip-is-in-a-network-in-python) should help you:

If you can't go for any reason on this link here is the answer:

```
import socket,struct

def makeMask(n):
    "return a mask of n bits as a long integer"
    return (2L<<n-1) - 1

def dottedQuadToNum(ip):
    "convert decimal dotted quad string to long integer"
    return struct.unpack('L',socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]

def networkMask(ip,bits):
    "Convert a network address to a long integer" 
    return dottedQuadToNum(ip) & makeMask(bits)

def addressInNetwork(ip,net):
   "Is an address in a network"
   return ip & net == net

address = dottedQuadToNum("192.168.1.1")
networka = networkMask("10.0.0.0",24)
networkb = networkMask("192.168.0.0",24)
print (address,networka,networkb)
print addressInNetwork(address,networka)
print addressInNetwork(address,networkb)
```

Return True or False (in the example first you have False then True).

Or in one function:

```
import socket,struct

def addressInNetwork(ip,net):
   "Is an address in a network"
   ipaddr = struct.unpack('L',socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]
   netaddr,bits = net.split('/')
   netmask = struct.unpack('L',socket.inet_aton(netaddr))[0] & ((2L<<int(bits)-1) - 1)
   return ipaddr & netmask == netmask
```

The answer is inspired by the question I linked, give credits to the people if it work for you.

Comment: Using netaddr you can test only "/32" Ip you cant search a range to range

Comment: No Problem Thanks :)