# Is checking if an IP is in a subnet doing network requests or local computing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ip, subnet

I have a list of client IPs and a list of subnetworks like so:

```
ips = ['firstIP','secondIP',....]
subnets = ['subnet1', 'subnet2',.....]
```

My ultimate goal is to find which subnetwork has at least one client who belongs to it.
Using what I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819355/how-can-i-check-if-an-ip-is-in-a-network-in-python) I created this function:

```
def ip_in_network(ips, network):
    for ip in ips:
        if ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(network):
            return True
    return False

lst = []
for network in subnets:
    if ip_in_network(ips, network):
        lst.append(network)
```

where `ips` is the list of ips that I have and `network` is an element from the list `subnets`.
Both my lists are very large and I would like to make this more efficient using parallel programing. I am contemplating between using the `threading` module and the `multiprocessing` module because I understand that one more suited for network bound problems and the other for CPU computations.
So my question is, is the line `ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(network)` preforming some network requests or is it all running locally? I couldn't find out from the documatation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any recommendations to make this code more efficient are welcome

Comment: ipaddress module does not need any network connection. Comparing adresses and subnet is just bit to bit comparaison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How did you come to this conclusion? I could not find anything in the documentation about it

Comment: In the source code there is no reference to socket or other network module.