# Best way to check if IP address is in IP range in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an AWS DynamoDB table that stores IP ranges with a pool_address, a mask and an identifier (that is originally coming from excel/csv), eg.:
pool_address is 100.150.200.0
mask is /22
identifier is myrange

I have about 250 of those.

Im trying to use Lambda to check if a given IP address is in any of the ranges and if yes, return the identifier.
E.g.:
IP 100.150.200.1 returns 'myrange'
IP 100.150.201.1 returns 'myrange'
IP 100.150.220.1 returns False
IP 100.150.199.1 returns False

I know PostreSQL has some specific datatypes (INET, CIDR) that would makes this a lot easier, but is there any good way to get this doen with DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself: Since I'm using Python in the Lambda code, I could simply use [ipAddress](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ipaddress-py/), as explained in this answer:
[How can I check if an ip is in a network in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819355/how-can-i-check-if-an-ip-is-in-a-network-in-python)

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1') in ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/24')
True
```